# Is there a function to find the current handler for the named route in my app

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I can get the currect app / WSGI instance with : `webapp2.get_app()` and the current request instance : `webapp2.get_request()` but how to get the current webapp2 handler instance from :

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

for :

webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=module.MainHandler, name='main'),
```

without using "self" to refer to this object. Is it possible?

The route object in the request object contains the handler name, but not the instance.

**UPDATE** : A solution has not been found yet. For now I store the handler (self) in a global, using dispatch of the `webapp2.RequestHandler`. But there must be another way.

To find a solution I study Nick Johnsonz "how to write your own Python webapp framework" : http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/Writing-your-own-webapp-framework-for-App-Engine to understand how webapp2 works.

What have I done :

With `webapp2.get_request()` I can find the `request.route` and the `request.route.handler_adapter` instance. But not the handler instance. The handler instance is not saved.

**Conclusion** : I use the constructor of my `webapp2.RequestHandler` to save the handler instance (self) in the request registry (threadsafe). And I do not have to match the route name, because for every request new instances (handler and request) are created.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Could you please provide a bit more context as to why the "self" is not what you are looking for?

Comment: I need the handler object in a sub sub sub function, where I did not pass the self. Ofcourse I can pass the self to the sub function and again to a sub function. But I am curious, can I get the handler instance using a webapp2 function.

Answer (score 1):

Your question (or perhaps the example code snippet) may need to be more well-defined in order for folks to provide a suitable answer.

As far as I can tell, you seem to be looking for a way to find the call stack of some function in order to determine the nearest `RequestHandler` instance. If that's the case, then this is more of a general Python question than webapp2, but the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) may be what you're looking for.